# Pandas dictionary transformation to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
mylist = [['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['b', 3], ['b', 4]]
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
```

and I would like to turn it into this

```
desired_dict = {'a':[1, 2], 'b':[3, 4]}
```

What is an elegant way to do that with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby(0)[1].agg(list).to_dict()
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thank you! :) I tried to accept and got an error, I will accept later

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
out = df.groupby(0)[1].apply(list).to_dict()
```

```
print(out)

{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
```

Comment: Thank you! appreciate your help